# How does a user submit an article on a website?

Tags: php

I am working on this travel blog Trippindian.com . I want to build a page where a user can login via facebook and then write an article and submit it to us. Its just like I am posting a question on stackoverflow.

just FYI I am a noobie coder.

I want to understand the logic and functionality behind this.

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like a fun project, but this is a bit too broad for Stack Overflow.  Search Google for some tutoriala, try it out, then come back when you have specific questions or if you get stuck.

Comment: look for wordpress plugins https://wordpress.org/plugins/tags/facebook-login

Comment: *"Its just like I am posting a question on stackoverflow"* - You seem to know how Stack works and what not to post. If not, go through this http://stackoverflow.com/help and the first 2 associated posts in that page on the left.

Answer (score -2):

First, you need a database where you can store all these posts.
And then, you would need to create a page with a form element (HTML).

You would also need a php code that connects to the database and adds the value or values contained in the form.

That's pretty much what you need.
You could find other solutions, but I think it's the simplest one.

Comment: *"First, you need a database where you can store all these posts."* - They don't "need" a database explicitly. They can run off of (text) files also. That question is way too broad.

Comment: *"but I think it's the simplest one."* - Running a database may be simplest for you and many others, but not for everyone. It's not "that" simple.

Comment: Of course. That's why there is a "I think" in the sentence :)